# How to add sound effect on closing a window?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, system-sounds

On windows system of course. 
When we close an file explorer window, is there a way to add sound effect?
The "closing application" doesn't work because of too many processes closed unnoticably. It seem should be opposite to "start navigation".

Answer (score 0):

Open Control Panel and click on Hardware and Sound. In Sound click on Change system sounds.

Choose the sound to associate to Close Program (close Window).

Comment: That would bring you unstoppable sounds continusly